# How can I know the source of Interop automatically built by VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, interop

**NOTE: the actual problem I was having building is fixed; a co-worker discovered that our IT department had pushed a new version of Acrobat Reader on us.  Uninstalled that, reinstalled the old version, and it builds fine now.  But I'm still curious if there's a way to know the basis for what appears to be an automatically generated interop.  Thanks.**

I feel like a real dope for not being able to figure this out, but it's just a topic I've somehow managed to avoid ever having to deal with.

I have an interop file (it happens to be AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll) that is automatically built when I build my project (I took this over from another programmer who is no longer on the scene).  How can I work backwards to figure out what file -- I assume a type library, or a dll -- this is built from?

I can use the object browser, and see that the methods I need aren't in it.  I can then copy a good version of AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll from another folder, and in the object browser everything is good; but then I build, and the AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll is overwritten with a version missing those methods.  I assume whatever file the dll is based upon, there must be two versions of THAT file on my computer; but I don't know what file to look for.

Thanks.

UPDATE at request of Hans Passant:

There are many methods missing from the interop -- the "bad' version that's getting built has only four:

- AttachInterfaces()
- AxAcroPDF()
- CreateSink()
- DetachSink()

The correct file adds:

- execCommand(object)
- GetVersions()
- goBackwardStack()
- goForwardStack()
- gotoFirstPage()
- gotoLastPage()
- gotoNextPage()
- gotoPreviousPage()
- LoadFile(string) <--- One of the methods I actually need
- postmessage(object)
- Print()
- printAll()
- printAllFit(bool)
- printPages(int, int)
- printWithDialog()
- setCurrentHighlight(int, int, int, int)
- setCurrentHightlight(int, int, int, int)
- setCurrentPage(int)
- setLayoutMode(string)
- setNamedDest(string)<----- the other one I need
- setPageMode(string)
- setShowScrollbars(bool)
- setShowToolbar(bool)
- setView(string)
- setViewRect(float, float, float, float)
- setViewScroll(string, float)
- setZoom(float)
- setZoomScroll(float, float, float)

... plus properties

- messageHandler
- src

... and events

- OnError
- OnMessage

Comment: Can we do this without having to guess what methods are missing?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be cryptic; I was mostly just trying to figure out what triggered building of the files, and what files they're based upon.  I've added a detailed list to the original post.